Users can't enable the reminder for the app
In my NET8 MAUI apps, I want to send a local notification every day to remind the user to use the app. For that, I'm using the component Plugin.LocalNotification. For Android, in the AndroidManifest.xml, I added those lines
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

Then I created a service to manage the notification and checked if the user gave the consent to use the app.
INotificationService _notificationService;

var notifyDateTime = 
    DateTime.Parse($"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()} 08:00:00");
var notification = new NotificationRequest
{
    NotificationId = 100,
    Title = AppResources.NotificationsTitle,
    Description = AppResources.NotificationDescription,
    CategoryType = NotificationCategoryType.Status,
    Android = new Plugin.LocalNotification.AndroidOption.AndroidOptions
    {
        AutoCancel = true,
        IconSmallName =
        {
            ResourceName = "noti_liulogo",
        },
        IconLargeName =
        {
            ResourceName = "liulogo",
        },
        LaunchAppWhenTapped = true,
        Priority = AndroidPriority.High
    },
    iOS =
    {
        HideForegroundAlert = true,
        PlayForegroundSound = true
    },
    Schedule =
    {
        NotifyTime = notifyDateTime,
        RepeatType = NotificationRepeat.Daily
    }
};

await _notificationService.Show(notification);

When the app runs this code, the user is redirected to the system page to enable Alarms and reminders but the switch is disabled.

What have I done wrong?
Update
An update. If I added in the AndroidManifest.xml the lines
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />

the application can send notifications but rejected by Google Play. Without those lines, the app shows the authorization page but I can't enable the notifications.

This is the same in emulators or real devices with Android API 33 or above.

I think you have to add more permissions if you're testing on new OS, newer OS requires more, have you tried that on an older device or simulator?

I tried on a few of them and also on real devices.

you can refer to use notification for tasks and add or edit a task
